# Computed column checksum persisted or not?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have created a computed column which is the checks`cs_file = (checksum([date],[file_name]))`
This column is used to search if file for a particular date already exists(using checksum to boost performance).
Select code:

```
select * from files where cs_file = checksum(@date,@filename) and date = @date and @filename = filename
```

The column is indexed. Will keeping the computed column persisted improve performance?
the table is not too large. data inserted in it is around 250 rows perday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be no difference in performance between an index on persisted vs nonpersisted column.

However, I hardly believe that you need it at all, a compound index on (date, file_name) or the other way round, depending on selectivity, should suffice.

I suggest to activated `SET STATISTICS IO ON` option on the session and after executing queries with and without the index on computed column and with and without the index on (date, file_name) check the logical reads. Less is better :)